# Best practice for secret environment variables in git

Tags: git, security, environment-variables

Is it safe to put secret environment variables (for example: database password) in git? If not, what is the best practice for it?

Comment: Absolutely not, that's why they're called *secret*. You put them in the environment, not the source control.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So how can I run git-ci without my env-vars?

Comment: You need to set the env vars in the CI environment, too. **Not** send them via source control. Read the docs for whatever CI you're using as to how to do that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean why ci environment is safe but source control is not?

Comment: If your CI environment *isn't* safe, you probably shouldn't put them there, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's possible to put secrets in your repository if you're using a custom solution like git-secrets or TravisCI's encrypted secrets, in general you don't want to do that, since anyone with a copy of your repository can access them.  Source code leaks more often than you might imagine, and even if it doesn't, an ordinary developer shouldn't have access to production credentials without a need to access them.

What you generally *do* want to do is pass your secrets into your code through the environment.  For CI, most CI systems have an encrypted, access-restricted tool that shares secrets only through the environment, and for deployment, many people use a similar tool such as Vault.  Most of these systems store credentials only in an encrypted state and use secret sharing such that it's very difficult to get credentials out of them without authorization, as well as ensure that credentials are accessible only in the proper environment: it isn't possible for developers to get access to these credentials just by having the repo.

And just to avoid any doubt, this isn't about trusting or not trusting people, it's about making sure that people don't accidentally leak information or do the wrong things with it (like use the production credentials when dropping a database).